# SQL query to filter records based on a particular column value along with descending date of insertion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this Table OPERATIONS-

```
AMOUNT  CLAIM_TYPE      INSERTED_DATE
100     SETT            09-SEP-18 10.37.50
1006    ATTAA           09-SEP-18 10.37.54
102320  FIXX            09-SEP-18 10.37.55
10077   SETT            09-SEP-18 10.37.56
10034   FIXX            09-SEP-18 10.37.57
900     ATTAA           09-SEP-18 10.37.58
```

---

I want to filter out the records based on the CLAIM_TYPE column value such that the **CLAIM_TYPE value appears only one time** and the record must be the **latest record** (inserted date).

```
SELECT TOTAL_RECEIVED_AMOUNT, CLAIM_TYPE, INSERTED_DATE
FROM OPERATION 
WHERE CLAIM_TYPE IN 
('FIXX', 'SETT', 'ATTAA', 'PLACC', 'THREE', 'SIXX','TWELL') ORDER BY INSERTED_DATE DESC ;
```

---

```
AMOUNT    CLAIM_TYPE  INSERTED_DATE
900       ATTAA       09-SEP-18 10.37.58
10034     FIXX        09-SEP-18 10.37.57
10077     SETT        09-SEP-18 10.37.56
102320    FIXX        09-SEP-18 10.37.55
1006      ATTAA       09-SEP-18 10.37.54
100       SETT        09-SEP-18 10.37.50
```

---

The expected result is-

```
    AMOUNT    CLAIM_TYPE  INSERTED_DATE
    900       ATTAA       09-SEP-18 10.37.58
    10034     FIXX        09-SEP-18 10.37.57
    10077     SETT        09-SEP-18 10.37.56
```

I am having difficulty in getting the same while trying count, having and group by clauses. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use corelated sub-query

```
select * from OPERATION op
     where op.INSERTED_DATE 
    in ( select max(INSERTED_DATE)
          from
          OPERATION op1
          where op1.CLAIM_TYPE=op.CLAIM_TYPE
          group by CLAIM_TYPE
        )
     and CLAIM_TYPE IN ('FIXX', 'SETT', 'ATTAA', 'PLACC', 'THREE', 'SIXX','TWELL')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT op.*
FROM (SELECT TOTAL_RECEIVED_AMOUNT, CLAIM_TYPE, INSERTED_DATE,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLAIM_TYPE ORDER BY INSERTED_DATE DESC) AS seq
      FROM OPERATION  op
      WHERE CLAIM_TYPE IN ('FIXX', 'SETT', 'ATTAA', 'PLACC', 'THREE', 'SIXX','TWELL')
     ) op
WHERE seq = 1;
```